# ¿Como ordenar datos de columnas a filas usando Python y Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

tengo un código que realizar la limpieza de un archivo de excel, ya tengo todo lo esencial, pero me falta un último paso, ordenar los datos, actualmente están así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero que los valores de las columnas 5G queden ahora en una solo columna con sus respectivos valores, de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo intente hacer con una pivot_table

```
pivot_table = df.pivot_table(index=['Fecha', 'Region', 'S/PGW Cisco', '5G SGW PDN Sessions', '5G PGW PDN Sessions'],
                             values=['5G SGW PDN Sessions', '5G PGW PDN Sessions'])
```

pero quedo igual que la primera imagen. Me podrían ayudar a como corregir y/o hace el cambio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes conseguir lo que buscas usando [`pandas.DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html#pandas.melt) de forma bastante directa:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Fecha": ("23/11/2023", "23/11/2023"),
    "Region": ("North", "North"),
    "S/PGW": ("MXTUM01SPGW01", "MXTUM01SPGW02"),
    "5G SGW": (40992, 41264),
    "5G PGW": (34479, 34313),
    "5g SAEGW": (1625.5, 1668)
})
```

---

```
>>> df
         Fecha  Region          S/PGW   5G SGW  5G PGW  5g SAEGW
0   23/11/2023   North  MXTUM01SPGW01    40992   34479    1625.5
1   23/11/2023   North  MXTUM01SPGW02    41264   34313    1668.0
```

Aplicando `melt` usando las tres primeras columnas como identificadores pivotamos las restantes:

```
df.melt(
    id_vars=['Fecha', 'Region', 'S/PGW'],
    var_name="Resource Name",
    value_name="Value"
    )

         Fecha Region           S/PGW   Resource Name     Value
0   23/11/2023  North   MXTUM01SPGW01          5G SGW   40992.0
1   23/11/2023  North   MXTUM01SPGW02          5G SGW   41264.0
2   23/11/2023  North   MXTUM01SPGW01          5G PGW   34479.0
3   23/11/2023  North   MXTUM01SPGW02          5G PGW   34313.0
4   23/11/2023  North   MXTUM01SPGW01        5g SAEGW    1625.5
5   23/11/2023  North   MXTUM01SPGW02        5g SAEGW    1668.0
```

Answer (score 0):

ya encontre como hacerlo.

```
df_melted = df.melt(id_vars=
                    ['Fecha', 'Region', 'S/PGW Cisco', var_name='Resource Name', value_name='Used Resources')
```

Con esto ya me da el resultado deseado.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).